# MySQL lock wait timeout when changing data-type

Tags: mysql, database

I wanted to change a column's data type from DATE to DATETIME with ALTER TABLE statement.  However, I got the lock wait timeout.  The table has 11634921 records.  I am wondering what would be the right way if my previous one was wrong.

Here is the query:

```
ALTER TABLE title_views CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at DATETIME NULL;
```

Comment: What was the query you used?

Comment: ALTER TABLE title_views
CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at DATETIME NULL;

Answer (score 0):

You should stop any clients which are currently reading/writing the table

OR

Create a fresh proper copy  of it and rename them and afterwards load the data from the old table

Comment: I tried the second method you suggested.  However, loading 11634921 from old table to new table also resulted in the lock wait timeout.  Would it make a difference if I duplicate the same table and operate on the newly created table?  After that, I can rename?

Comment: _Would it make a difference if I duplicate the same table and operate on the newly created table? After that, I can rename?_ - that's what I meant!

Comment: I fired 2 SQL now.  CREATE TABLE title_views_new2 LIKE title_views; 
INSERT title_views_new2 SELECT * FROM title_views;  But I am not sure how long it will take.  I tried it before and it ended up with lock wait timeout.  I'll try it one more time and keep you posted.

Comment: Failed - 09:42:40 INSERT title_views_new2 SELECT * FROM title_views Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 599.978 sec.  I think copying data takes too long.